# onmouseout not fired when performed dom manipulation chrome firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-manipulation, onmouseout

Onmouseout seems not working properly when DOM underneath the mouse is changed. I have found out that this is known bug of innerHTML implementation in firefox (quite old) [Firefox Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60480). There is however workaround (avoiding innerHTML). I have created demonstration here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhthD/)

Code js:

```
test = document.getElementById('test');


test.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor='blue';   
}

test.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor='red';   
}

window.onkeyup = function() {
  var test  = document.getElementById('test');
  var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
  var f;  

  var sp1 = document.createElement("div");
  var sp1_content = document.createTextNode("Test");   

  sp1.appendChild(sp1_content);    
  //sp1.innerHTML = 'Test<br />Test';
  sp1.id = 'test2'


  insertedElement = test.insertBefore(sp1, test2 );
  test2.style.height='0px';

  //replacedNode = test.replaceChild(sp1, test2);    

  //test.innerHTML = 'Test';  
  //alert(1);
  f = function() {
    test.removeChild(test2);
  }

  setTimeout(f,1000);
}
```

Code HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id='test' style='background-color:red;'>
    <div id='test2'>  
      Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When you hover over the element it changes color. When you are over it and press some button, the element is changed and mouse is not over it any more (onmouseout event should be triggered). This workaround works in firefox, but not in chrome. Is there any way how to properly detect onmouseout? I have read something about mutation events, however I would consider these as last resort as they have performance impact. As I am not using any framework yet, I would like not to use it just to resolve this ridiculous issue. Use-case for this is custom drop-down menu with variable height with search functionality which has some onmouseover/onmouseout styling changes (similar to native select field).

Comment: Works perfectly for me (Chrome 28.0.1500.71 / Ubuntu)

Comment: Well the div stays blue when you are over it and press button. Should be red (as onmouseout event changes color to red). I have  28.0.1500.72 m / Win XP, tested also on Win 7. :/